# Module parse failed: Unexpected token. react-native/index.js "typeof" operator

Tags: reactjs, react-native, webpack, node-modules, typeof

I'm quite new to the front end - trying to implement client side on React. After adding "react-native" dependency and running `webpack` I'm getting the following error:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/react-native/index.js 13:7
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (13:7)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| 'use strict';
| 
> import typeof AccessibilityInfo from './Libraries/Components/AccessibilityInfo/AccessibilityInfo';
| import typeof ActivityIndicator from './Libraries/Components/ActivityIndicator/ActivityIndicator';
| import typeof Button from './Libraries/Components/Button';
 @ ./node_modules/@react-navigation/native/lib/module/useBackButton.js 2:0-43 5:25-36
 @ ./node_modules/@react-navigation/native/lib/module/index.js
 @ ./src/main/js/app.js
```

I have the following dependencies in package.json:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.7",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.1.4",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.2.9",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-native": "^0.62.1",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.6.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.7.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^0.7.3",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.4.0",
    "rest": "^2.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "watch": "webpack --watch -d"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.9.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.9.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.9.4",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "webpack": "^4.42.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.11"
  }
```

I assume that "typeof" operator is not recognized, but why?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I just spent a few hours dealing with this exact issue.

First, you can try adding [`"@babel/preset-flow"`](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-flow) to your `.babelrc` file (after installing). That was recommended [here](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-linear-gradient/issues/196), but didn't actually work for me.

What worked for me was just adding `externals: { "react-native": true },` to my `webpack.config.js` file. My config file ended up looking like this:

```js
const path = require("path")

module.exports = {
    entry: "./src/index.js",
    output: {
        filename: "main.js",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    },
    externals: {
        "react-native": true,
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: ["babel-loader"],
            },
            // ...
        ],
    },
}
```

My understanding is that `react-native` is a dependency, so [`@babel/preset-flow`](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-flow) didn't actually get triggered to help interpret the `flow` formatting in those files - it may only handle files in the main `"entry"` location of your `webpack.config.js` file.

Hopefully this helps someone out there. Feel free to comment on this answer if I'm a bit off-base and I'll update this :)

Answer (score 5):

Do you try to run React Native in the browser? If yes, I recommend using [React Native for Web](https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web).

`react-native` can not run in the browser. You need to add an alias from `react-native` to `react-native-web` in `webpack.config.js`, so this package is used instead.

Following the [React Native for Web documentation](http://necolas.github.io/react-native-web/docs/?path=/docs/overview-getting-started--page#configuring-a-module-bundler) you need to make this modification to your webpack config:

```js
// webpack.config.js
module.exports = {
    // ...the rest of your config

    resolve: {
        alias: {
            'react-native$': 'react-native-web'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what can I do in expo?

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded my expo app SDK from 43 to 48 and had this issue. this solution is for you if you are using expo react native.
Copy this code and paste in your `babel.config.js`

```
module.exports = function(api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
    plugins: ['react-native-reanimated/plugin'], 
  };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue before. The solution was to add the following to the webpack.config.js file:

```js
externals: {
    "react-native": true,
},
```

The externals option is used to specify which modules are external, meaning they will not be bundled into the output bundle. Instead, they will be obtained from the environment at runtime. This is commonly used to treat certain modules (such as React Native) as external dependencies, reducing the size of the bundled output and obtaining these modules at runtime from the global scope or other environments.

Here is my webpack.config.js file

```js
// Generated using webpack-cli https://github.com/webpack/webpack-cli

const path = require('path');
const WorkboxWebpackPlugin = require('workbox-webpack-plugin');
const isProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV == 'production';


const config = {
    entry: './src/index.ts',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    },
    externals: {
        "react-native": true,
    },
    devServer: {
        open: true,
        host: 'localhost',
    },
    plugins: [

        // Add your plugins here
        // Learn more about plugins from https://webpack.js.org/configuration/plugins/
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(ts|tsx)$/i,
                loader: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: ['/node_modules/'],
            },
            {
                test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|png|jpg|gif)$/i,
                type: 'asset',
            },

            // Add your rules for custom modules here
            // Learn more about loaders from https://webpack.js.org/loaders/
        ],
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.jsx', '.js', '...'],
    },
};

module.exports = () => {
    if (isProduction) {
        config.mode = 'production';
        

        config.plugins.push(new WorkboxWebpackPlugin.GenerateSW());
        
    } else {
        config.mode = 'development';
    }
    return config;
};
```