# SyntaxError: Unexpected token typeof

Tags: react-native

When i perform `yarn test` getting this issue

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token typeof
```

[image]

Not used `typeof` in the project but it's used in `react-native` package. Also gone through this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61035800/module-parse-failed-unexpected-token-react-native-index-js-typeof-operator), accepted answer is not working and another answer (adding `react-native-web` package) is giving some other problems.

Do we have any solution to solve this problem

**Edit**
package.json

```
{
  "name": "xxxx",
  "version": "x.x.xx",
  "description": "xxx",
  "author": "xxx",
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "node scripts/dev-server.js",
    "build": "bin/build",
    "build:mobile": "bin/build-mobile",
    "start": "npm run dev",
    "start:mobile": "bin/start-mobile",
    "android": "bin/android",
    "ios": "bin/ios",
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.jsx src",
    "lint-fix": "eslint --fix --ext .js,.jsx src",
    "test": "jest",
    "validate": "yarn test",
    "snapshot": "jest --updateSnapshot",
    "test:mobile": "bin/test-mobile",
    "eject:mobile": "bin/eject-mobile",
    "prepublishOnly": "yarn build",
    "configureConsumerRepo": "git submodule init && yarn pullConsumerRepo",
    "pullConsumerRepo": "git submodule update --remote --merge",
    "patch": "npm version patch -m \"Upgrade to %s\"",
    "mobile": "yarn build:mobile && yarn start:mobile"
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-push": "yarn validate"
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "chroma-js": "^1.3.4",
    "moment": "^2.19.3",
    "react-native-parsed-text": "^0.0.20",
    "scroll-into-view": "^1.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.22.1",
    "babel-eslint": "^8.0.1",
    "babel-jest": "^21.2.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.3.2",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-register": "^6.22.0",
    "chalk": "^2.0.1",
    "connect-history-api-fallback": "^1.3.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.0",
    "cssnano": "^3.10.0",
    "enzyme": "^3.1.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.0.1",
    "enzyme-to-json": "^3.1.2",
    "eslint": "^4.8.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^16.0.0",
    "eslint-friendly-formatter": "^3.0.0",
    "eslint-import-resolver-webpack": "^0.8.3",
    "eslint-loader": "^1.9.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.7.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.0.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.4.0",
    "eventsource-polyfill": "^0.9.6",
    "express": "^4.14.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.0",
    "file-loader": "^0.11.1",
    "friendly-errors-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.3",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.28.0",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "^0.17.3",
    "husky": "^1.0.0-rc.1",
    "jest-cli": "^21.2.1",
    "jest-junit": "^3.3.0",
    "jest-styled-components": "^4.9.0",
    "normalize.css": "^7.0.0",
    "opn": "^5.1.0",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.0",
    "ora": "^1.2.0",
    "postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "^3.2.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^2.0.6",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.0",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.0.0-rc.3",
    "react-helmet": "^5.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.63.4",
    "react-native-mock-render": "^0.0.16",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-select": "^2.1.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.2.0",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.0",
    "semver": "^5.3.0",
    "shelljs": "^0.7.6",
    "style-loader": "^0.19.0",
    "styled-components": "^2.2.1",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.8",
    "wdio-mocha-framework": "^0.5.11",
    "wdio-sauce-service": "^0.4.4",
    "webdriverio": "^4.9.11",
    "webpack": "^2.6.1",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^2.2.1",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.10.0",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.18.0",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "notify": true,
    "setupFiles": [
      "<rootDir>/src/components/__tests__/shim.js"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/src/components/__tests__/assetsTransformer.js",
      "\\.(css|less)$": "<rootDir>/src/components/__tests__/assetsTransformer.js"
    },
    "snapshotSerializers": [
      "enzyme-to-json/serializer"
    ],
    "testPathIgnorePatterns": [
      "<rootDir>/src/components/__tests__/shim.js",
      "<rootDir>/src/components/__tests__/utils.js",
      "<rootDir>/src/components/__tests__/assetsTransformer.js",
      "<rootDir>/webdriverio-test/"
    ]
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 10.0.0",
    "npm": ">= 6.0.0"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not ie <= 8"
  ],
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react-native-fast-image": "^5.2.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Post your package.json. Hard to say for sure but looks like typescript

Comment: @JaredSmith kindly check the edit

Comment: I can't reproduce. Just guessing, but I suspect you'll have to wait for someone with a windows box to give it a go. If you have WSL or another virtualization option handy then I'd suggest trying that.