# react-native-web can't compile because 'BackHandler' module not found in react navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, webpack, react-navigation, react-native-web

react-native-web is not compiling because it is not able to find BackHandler Module exported by `react-native` used in `react-navigation` v6.
[image]

The project was created with react-native cli with react-native version 0.70.2. I had issues with installing react-native-web because of difference in react version in latest react native and react native web. Had to force install canary version.

Still I think react-native-web should handle default react-native native platform code.
Below is my webpack config - taken from [here](https://arry.medium.com/how-to-add-react-native-web-to-an-existing-react-native-project-eb98c952c12f).

```
const path = require('path');

const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

const appDirectory = path.resolve(__dirname);
const {presets} = require(`${appDirectory}/babel.config.js`);

const compileNodeModules = [
    // Add every react-native package that needs compiling
    'react-native-gesture-handler',
    // '@react-navigation',
].map(moduleName => path.resolve(appDirectory, `node_modules/${moduleName}`));

const babelLoaderConfiguration = {
    test: /\.js$|tsx?$/,
    // Add every directory that needs to be compiled by Babel during the build.
    include: [
        path.resolve(__dirname, 'index.web.js'), // Entry to your application
        path.resolve(__dirname, 'App.web.tsx'), // Change this to your main App file
        path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
        path.resolve(appDirectory, 'node_modules/react-native-uncompiled'),
        ...compileNodeModules,
    ],
    use: {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
            cacheDirectory: true,
            presets,
            plugins: ['react-native-web'],
        },
    },
};

const svgLoaderConfiguration = {
    test: /\.svg$/,
    use: [
        {
            loader: '@svgr/webpack',
        },
    ],
};

const imageLoaderConfiguration = {
    test: /\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$/,
    use: {
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
            name: '[name].[ext]',
        },
    },
};

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: path.join(__dirname, 'index.web.js'),
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(appDirectory, 'dist'),
        publicPath: '/',
        filename: 'rnw_blogpost.bundle.js',
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.web.tsx', '.web.ts', '.tsx', '.ts', '.web.js', '.js'],
        alias: {
            'react-native$': 'react-native-web',
        },
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            babelLoaderConfiguration,
            imageLoaderConfiguration,
            svgLoaderConfiguration,
        ],
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'),
        }),
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            // See: https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web/issues/349
            __DEV__: JSON.stringify(true),
        }),
    ],
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Adding

```
externals: {
    "react-native": true,
},
```

to webpack.config.js worked for me. Solution taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61035800/module-parse-failed-unexpected-token-react-native-index-js-typeof-operator)